# data sources won't appear on devexpress blazor reportdesigner

Tags: .net-core, devexpress, reporting, blazor, designer

I'm creating a web app using devexpress blazor reporting that contains a simple page

```
<div style="margin: auto; width: 80%;">
    <DxReportDesigner
        ReportUrl="HelloWorld" Height="1000px" Width="100%" AllowMDI="true">
            <DxReportDesignerWizardSettings UseFullscreenWizard="false"/>
    </DxReportDesigner>
</div>
```

Based on documentation I've registered the data source wizard type provider on the Startup.cs file

```
services.AddScoped<ReportStorageWebExtension, ReportStorageWebExtension1>();
            
            DevExpress.XtraReports.Web.ReportDesigner
                .DefaultReportDesignerContainer.RegisterObjectDataSourceWizardTypeProvider<GDataTypeProvider>();
```

My GDataTypeProvider looks like this:

```
public class GDataTypeProvider : IObjectDataSourceWizardTypeProvider {

        public IEnumerable<Type> GetAvailableTypes(string context) {
            return new[] {
                typeof(SampleObjectTypes.DataSource),
                typeof(SampleObjectTypes.DataSource2)
            };
        }
```

When I run the project the designer shows  the 'Add Data Source' is not visible, what am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 0):

You need to register your implementation of the `IObjectDataSourceWizardTypeProvider` as described in the [Register the Declared Types](https://docs.devexpress.com/XtraReports/401230/web-reporting/asp-net-core-reporting/end-user-report-designer/bind-to-data/register-types-for-object-data-source-wizard#register-the-declared-types) help topic:

```cs
using DevExpress.DataAccess.Web;
...
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.ConfigureReportingServices(configurator => {
       configurator.ConfigureReportDesigner(designerConfigurator => {       
          designerConfigurator.RegisterObjectDataSourceWizardTypeProvider<GDataTypeProvider>();
       });
   });
}
```

The way you are doing this now is applicable for ASP.NET WebForms / MVC applications only.